# module.function is not a function after moving to server

Tags: node.js

I moved a small application to my server. I was running locally on my macbook pro and everything was working perfectly. When moving to a server it is saying a function in one of my exports is not a function.

I can provide some code if necessary but are there any main things to check?

Changing file names, printing out what is in the variable

Comment: It could be the ecma version you are using not supported on the server. Possibly you are using arrow functions. If you include some code snippet of that function then we can help you better

Comment: Check Node versions both on your local machine and on your server (run `node --version` to check that). If it's different, install the same or better even newer version on your server, maybe it can help.

And you'd better provide some code). At least the code of your module and of the file which imports your module.